# Javascript parser to add percentages to non-percentages

Tags: javascript, mathjs

Looking for a consistent way to write (or extend) a parser to do math equations. I'm using [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/) for most of this, and it works great. But it does not handle percentages. I'm trying to write rules that will handle adding percentages to percentages, percentages to non-percentages, etc..

1 + 6 + 7% = 7.49 – correct .
1 + 6 + 7% = 7.07 – incorrect .

56.47 + 15% = 64.9405 – correct .
56.47 + 15% = 56.62 – incorrect .

etc..

Any tips or suggestion welcome.

Comment: Adding numbers with percentages doesn't make much sense. It's like adding apples with pears. If you consider `7%` as a shortcut of `7% of 1` (which is `0.07`) then `1 + 6 + 7% = 7.07` is the correct equation.

Comment: It doesn't but people will do it. Google `1 + 6 + 7%` and Google will give you an answer.

Comment: It's not the only incorrect answer that Google provides.

Comment: It's the answer Google's Calculator provides ;)

Comment: In this case, Google is wrong (as in many other cases). It provides different answers for `1 + 6 + 7%` and `6 + 1 + 7%`. Did the math changed recently?

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to Google to find out..

Comment: Why is 7% 0.49? I think that's 7%*7.

Comment: You mean `7.49`? Where is `0.49`?

Comment: Hmmm... Google calculator tries to mimic the way the real desk and hand calculators. Such a calculator computes partial results every time an operator is typed. Google implements it only partially and does it wrong, trying to use the correct operators precedence. Hence different results (and different than the one you get using a desk calculator) for the two expressions above.

Comment: yea it's odd that `1 + 6 + 7%` and `6 + 1 + 7%` result in different values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
      Number.prototype.plusPecentage = function(n){    
        return this+(this*n/100);
      }
    
      console.log((1 + 6).plusPecentage(7))
```

Or this:

```js
Math.plusPecentage = function(n,p){
  return n+(n*p/100);
}

console.log(Math.plusPecentage(7,7))
```

You could also do the same but extending **mathjs** library doing `math.plusPecentage = function () {//code}`